# Python Pandas: sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 10

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, partial

I am trying to iterate a list of strings using `dataframe1` to check whether the other `dataframe2` has any strings found in `dataframe1` to replace them.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print( row['x1'] )
    df2['strings'].str.replace(row['x1'],"")
```

In order to do this I iterated using the code shown above to check and replace for any string found in `df1`

```
wait_timeout
interactive_timeout
pool_recycle
....
__all__
folder_name
re.compile('he(lo') <= error string
```

However, while iterating it attempts to replace the string `re.compile('he(lo')` but is unable to as the string has "(()" brackets which are uneven. I have read other discussions that replace uses reg expressions and I can fix it by using `/(`. So I attempted to use:

```
replace = row['x1'].str.replace("(","\(")
replace = replace.str.replace(")","\)")
```

But I received an error on `replace = replace.str.replace(")","\)")` stating that

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

You're already assigning a string object to `replace`, so it doesn't have any attributes called `str`.

You can fix that with `replace = replace.replace(")","\)")`, although you might want to consider renaming that `replace` variable e.g.: `some_other_name = replace.replace(")","\)")`